# nfc pn544 write tag's

Tags: linux, drivers, nfc

I'm trying to write nfc tag's like you can with the libnfc software. The only problem is that my reader, the pn544 is not supported by libnfc. I installed NEARD but I can't write with that. Does anyone know how to get the same functionality of libnfc or get it supported with a drive of some sort. Thanks in advange.

Answer (score 0):

A kernel driver as well as a hardware-abstraction library for NXP's PN544 are available as part of the Android AOSP, so you may be able to port those to your platform.

- [Kernel driver](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/exynos/+/android-exynos-manta-3.4-kitkat-mr2/drivers/nfc/)
- [hardware-bastraction layer / libnfc-nxp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libnfc-nxp/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1)
- [software implementation based on libnfc-nxp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1)